# Allow users to post comment to a blog in SharePoint 2010 with out seeing the blog

Tags: security, blog

I am currently trying to create a blog on our IT sub site where we discuss various topics.  We would like to make it possible that every end user is able to make a post/comment on improvements they would like see on  the blog but we do not want them to see the blog its self and its various topics.  Is there a way to do this with SharePoint 2010 out of the box? I was poking around the various web parts but did not see anything, and Google was leading me to nothing.

Background info: 
SharePoint 2010 (On prem) 
I am newish to SharePoint (but falling in love with it)
Location of blog is locked down so only IT personal can see it

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try defining your requirements in a non-technical sense.  You need a place where people make suggestions, and you need a secure place where IT personnel comment and discuss these suggestions.

To accomplish this, create a support site where your users can add their suggestions to a list.  Then keep your blog locked down.  This is clean and simple, and doesn't require a lot of custom permission complexity.

Your initial thought of having users somehow make comments to a blog they cannot see might work, but you might end up having to do a lot of unnecessary work to get the security right.

Comment: Thanks for the idea Derek, I will run this by the powers to be and see what they say.  I am going to mark you answer as the correct one since you at least gave me a simple alternative.